# WCF service as internal and internet exposed on different servers

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, iis, wcf-proxy

I have to distribute several applications in 2 servers. Currently both servers have public IPs and they can be accesed across internet requests. Both servers are hosting several Web Applications. Now, I have to distribute those applications to have the front-end in the server  (A) and the back-end in the second (B), so that the server "B" doesn't have public internet conection, all the request must enter by the server "A" first. I am going to use WCF to separate and communicate the presentation with the program's logic (between those servers).  That's ok but, the problem is that the server "B" is hosting some public business WCF services consumed by external systems. Those business services need to be accesed directly across internet.

I have to provide a public service to recieve the calls and another in the server "B" to process the logic and perform database operations.

I don´t know what can be the best way to achieve this application distribution. I am taking create 2 services  as the last option. I think there must be a better solution like configuration or with infraestructure.

I hope you can give some idea to solve my issue.

Thanks in advance. 
Israel.

Answer (score 0):

It means that you go to expose server "B" to internet, right?
I'd consider to use 2 endpoints with 2 dif. contracts - 1 for your business services (ssl, certificate . . .?) And second one - for server "A" operations  (net.tcp binding, port opened for server "A" only).

Comment: The sever B cannot have a public end point, it only can be consumed by the server A. I don't know if the only way to achieve it is create a service in the server A that recieves the request just to resend it to the service in the server B.